# Highlight text in EditText when keyboard opens

Tags: android, keyboard

I'd like to highlight the text in an EditText when a keyboard opens for user input (this could be a hardware keyboard or the virtual keyboard).

Highlighting isn't my problem, my problem is a trigger to highlight.  Is there a handler that gets executed when the keyboard appears on a specific View (in this case, my EditText)?  Are there different handlers for hardware keyboard vs virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't get notified of those things at that level.  Why not just highlight it when the EditText gets focus?  In practice this will generally mean that an IME is displayed.

In fact, there is already a method to do exactly this: [setSelectAllOnFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSelectAllOnFocus%28boolean%29).

Comment: Hmm... I've tried this out, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I added "android:selectAllOnFocus="true"" to the EditText in the XML, but when I run the app in the emulator, nothing is selected.  I should also notice that this EditText is the first thing that is selected when the Activity launches

Comment: If I take focus away and bring it back, it highlights.  However, this still presents a problem.  Say I click on the EditText, it highlights, I change the value (it is no longer highlighted), I click the EditText again to bring the virtual keyboard back up, the text needs to be highlighted and it is not.  Maybe using the onClick handler would suffice for this, but it would not work when the user slides out a hardware keyboard

Comment: I think I've successfully done what I've set out, though it's cumbersome.  1) setSelectAllOnFocus. 2) selectAll when the EditText's onClick handler fires. 3) When the Activity is being created, if the EditText has focus and a hardware keyboard is present, selectAll

Comment: RE: your last comment.  2) Causes the DONE button in soft keyboard to not work in my test.